# How to post the exact number of values which are retrieved from post processor?

Tags: jmeter

I'm landing into a page where some Customers listed out. I'm retriving all the Customer Ids by Regular Expression Extractor Post-Processor.

Now, in a subsequent request I need to pass those Ids. It's being passed as a 'Body Data' by the following format:

```
[19327,15947,14421,18813,20942]
```

Let say, there are 5 Customer Ids retrived, then I can use the variables for each record as follows:

Passing Variables: `[${CustomerId_1},${CustomerId_2},${CustomerId_3},${CustomerId_5}]`
Posting Variable Values: `[19327,15947,14421,18813,20942]`

But let say, there are only 3 Customer Ids retrived, and if I pass the variables as above then the sampler will fail because currently it just retrived 3 Customer Id records.

Passing Variables: `[${CustomerId_1},${CustomerId_2},${CustomerId_3},${CustomerId_5}]`
Posting Variable Values: `[19327,15947,14421,${CustomerId_4},${CustomerId_5}]`

How to deal with this issue, plz. do help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Add [Beanshell PreProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PreProcessor) as a child of your 2nd request
2. Put the following code into the Pre-Processor's "Script" area

   ```
   int customers = Integer.parseInt(vars.get("CustomerId_matchNr"));
   StringBuilder requestBuilder = new StringBuilder();
   requestBuilder.append("[");
   for (int i = 1; i <= customers; i++) {
       requestBuilder.append(vars.get("CustomerId_" + i));
       if (i != customers) {
           requestBuilder.append(",");
       }
   }
   requestBuilder.append("]");

   sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).setValue(requestBuilder.toString());
   ```

The above code will build required request line depending on number of matches and automatically set request body.

Referenced classes:

- `vars` - shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html)
- `sampler` - provides access to the parent sampler, in case of HTTP Request it will be [HTTPSamplerProxy](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/protocol/http/sampler/HTTPSamplerProxy.html)
- [StringBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) - comes with Java SDK

See [How to Use BeanShell: JMeter's Favorite Built-in Component](https://blazemeter.com/blog/queen-jmeters-built-componentshow-use-beanshell) guide for more information on Beanshell scripting, explanation of pre-defined variables and some useful examples.

Answer (score 0):

`refName_matchNr` will return the number of matches. So in your case `CustomerId_matchNr` will give you number of customerIDs.

Use a beanshell pre-processor to run a loop and construct the BodyData string and save it to a new variable, use that variable in your subsequent sampler.